# Put watermark on image that load from DB - php

Tags: php

I had the below code that load image from DB. There are more than 600 rows of image has been inserted into the DB. I need the script that can perform these action:

Step 1) Load the image from DB
Step 2) process the image by putting the watermark
Step 3) Output the image to the browser.

I had the below code, that load and show the image. but I don't have any idea how to do the watermark.

```
$dbconn = @mysql_connect($mysql_server,$mysql_manager_id,$mysql_manager_pw) or exit("SERVER Unavailable"); 
@mysql_select_db($mysql_database,$dbconn) or exit("DB Unavailable"); 

$sql = "SELECT type,content FROM upload WHERE id=". $_GET["imgid"]; 

$result = @mysql_query($sql,$dbconn) or exit("QUERY FAILED!"); 

$contenttype = @mysql_result($result,0,"type"); 
$image = @mysql_result($result,0,"content"); 


header("Content-type: $contenttype"); 
echo $image;

mysql_close($dbconn); 

?>
```

Please help...

Comment: Look into [imagecopymerge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) Also, this script is vulnerable to sql injection, you should probably fix that as well.

Comment: Don't do this 'on the fly'. Process your watermarks ahead of time. Also, you should probably avoid serving images from the db. It's fine to store them there but you should dump them out as files and serve them from the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get the solution, here is the code:

```
<?php

$dbconn = @mysql_connect($mysql_server,$mysql_manager_id,$mysql_manager_pw) or exit("SERVER Unavailable"); 
@mysql_select_db($mysql_database,$dbconn) or exit("DB Unavailable"); 

$sql = "SELECT id, original_name, type, content FROM upload WHERE id=". $_GET["imgid"]; 

$result = @mysql_query($sql,$dbconn) or exit("QUERY FAILED!"); 

$fileID = @mysql_result($result,0,"id");
$contenttype = @mysql_result($result,0,"type"); 
$filename = @mysql_result($result,0,"original_name");
$image = @mysql_result($result,0,"content"); 


$fileXtension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$finalFileName = $fileID.".".$fileXtension;

// put the file on temporary folder
$filePutPath = "/your/temporary/folder/".$finalFileName;

// put the contents onto file system
file_put_contents($filePutPath, $image);


// get the watermark image
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('../images/watermark.png');

switch($fileXtension)
{
  case 'JPEG':
  case 'JPG' :
  case 'jpg' :
  case 'jpeg':
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePutPath);
  break;

  case 'gif' :
  case 'GIF' :
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($filePutPath);
  break;

  case 'png' :
  case 'PNG' :
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($filePutPath);
  break;

  default :
  break;
}

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filePutPath);

// set area for the watermark to be repeated
imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

// Set the tile (Combine the source image and the watermark image together)
imagesettile($im, $stamp);

// Make the watermark repeat the area
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $width, $height, IMG_COLOR_TILED);


header("Content-type: $contenttype"); 

// free the memory
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);

// delete the file on temporary folder
unlink($filePutPath);

mysql_close($dbconn); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could ether learn how to manipulate images on your own from php.net or you just get a package like the one below:
http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Tools
(Tools collection of common image manipulations. Available extensions are Blend, Border, Marquee, Mask, Swap, Thumbnail and **Watermark**.)

Answer (score 0):

How about calling your image the same way you do for the SELECT type, content?

Select the image with an imagepath from your database and then style it so it floats over your information. you could also hardcode the watermark image as it is always the same image you can have repeated. You won't see your information but if you put an opacity on the image, you can see through it:

```
#img.watermark {
    float:left;
    opacity:0.1;
    z-index:1;
}
```

This is just one idea on how to do it, but should work quite nicely!

Comment: Using CSS won't change the image itself, so anyone copies the image from your site it won't have the watermark - I assume the whole idea of using the watermark is to prevent others using the original image?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at

```
imagecopymerge()
```

from php's graphics librabry, it should do what you're looking for.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php